# Transactions not working properly in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
    $debit_array = $this->input->post('debit[]');
    $credit_array = $this->input->post('credit[]');

    if(array_sum($debit_array) == array_sum($credit_array)){
        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->where('Entry_id',$this->input->post('entry_id'));
        $this->db->delete('mk_account_transaction_master');

        $uniqueid = uniqid();
        $uniquecode = "Upadte Entry-".array_sum($debit_array)."-".$uniqueid;


    //  $this->db->trans_start();
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($debit_array);$i++){

            $insert_data = array(
                'account_date' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('date'))),
                'books' => $this->input->post('branch'),
                'account' => $this->input->post('account['.$i.']'),
                'debit' => $this->input->post('debit['.$i.']'),
                'credit' =>$this->input->post('credit['.$i.']'),
                'remarks' =>$this->input->post('remarks['.$i.']'),
                'updated_by' => $this->session->userdata(''),
                'entry_id' => $uniquecode,
                'display_item_id' => $disp1_id,
                'type' => $acc1_type,
                'group_id' => $grp1_id,
                'CF_Type' => $cf1_type,
                'Last_update_time' => date('Y-m-d H:m:s'),
            );
            $this->db->insert('mk_account_transaction_master',$insert_data);
        }
        $this->db->trans_complete();
    return 1;
```

}

I can use trans_start() and trans_complete(). The above function will first delete some data and then insert some data. If the insert code raises any database error, the delete query rolls back, but my code delete function does not roll back

`'updated_by' => $this->session->userdata('')` In this Line updated_by columns is assigned Null value, so Sql raises Error

> "Updated_by column can not   be null"

Therefore I want to rollback deleted data, using transactions. But no rollback of deleted data occurs.

Why are transactions not working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code Was Correct.But I used MyISAM Table So Transactions doesn't Affect These kind of table.SO I changed Type of table MyISAM to InnoDb

Now It's Works well